# Bubblesort is not working for large arrays

Tags: python, histogram, bubble-sort

I am trying to bubblesort a histogram of a gray image in python and I use the following function to bubblesort the histogram.

```
def bubbleSort(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        for j in range(len(arr) - 1):
        
            if arr[j] > arr[j+1]:
                prev = arr[j]
                arr[j] = arr[j+1]
                arr[j+1] = prev
```

I retrieve the histogram of the image as follows using opencv:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('path/to/image')

img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

histr = cv2.calcHist([img],[0],None,[256],[0,256])
histr = np.array(histr)
```

The bubblesort function seems to work when the array is not as big as the histogram.

But when I try to bubblesort the histogram of the image all of the values except for the last 3 gets the minimum value of the histogram.

I am now using sorting function of the numpy but I am curious.

Why is my function is not sorting the large arrays?

EDIT:
Download the image in this link: https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/colorful-massive-crowd-people-sit-event-big-crowd-people-125917596.jpg

Run the following code with the downloaded image to recreate the error.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread(r'path\to\image')

img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

histr = cv2.calcHist([img],[0],None,[256],[0,256])

histr = np.array(histr)
def bubbleSort(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        for j in range(len(arr) - 1):

            if arr[j] > arr[j+1]:
                prev = arr[j]
                arr[j] = arr[j+1]
                arr[j+1] = prev

bubbleSort(histr) # this outputs wrong
histr = np.sort(histr, axis=None) # this outputs without problems
```

Comment: The answer lies in something ;you _haven't_ shown us. But, since we haven't seen it, we can't tell you what that is ;-) That's why the site docs so strongly encourage presenting _all_ the info necessary for readers to _reproduce_ your problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have edited the question. the problem occurs when trying to bubblesort the histograms as I stated in the question before. I recreated the same error using different images.

Comment: Please read the article I linked to. It doesn't matter whether _you_ can reproduce the problem when you're asking _others_ for help. It only matters whether _they_ can reproduce the problem on their own. For example, work to get images and numpy (etc) out of this entirely. lf your function has a problem sorting some array, the only things you should need to show _us_ are your code and a specific array it fails to sort correctly. I don't know of any - your function works (albeit slowly) on every list I've tried.